# Is it Possible to do the small quick animation in splash screen in iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator

In My Splash Screen of application I want to do some animation as like moving of text or blinking of text, etc. I know that iPhone not support flash, but we can do this animation in our own way as like animation given by sdk. So is it possible to Blinking or text in Splash Screen, or the moving of text from one side to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Depending on what your "splash screen" is made of, you can probably use UIView's animation blocks to perform simple animations. Here's what I'd do:

- Make a UIView "wrapper" for the whole shebang.
- In the UIView show your background image and text etc.
- Reference the text in your View Controller through an outlet.
- Animate it using [UIView animate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) blocks. That should pretty much cover most basic animation needs.

Comment: Thanks Moshe. I will do it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I upvoted the answer, even though I'm severely against blinking anything at the start of, well, anything. I would more than likely stop using whatever app this becomes if I was accosted by such annoyances. Just like I do for websites.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the splash screen (Default.png) however, you can certainly create a UIView with your text and animation in it.  Make the background of the UIView your Default.png splash screen.  Add your animation and text.  Create a var in your application delegate to store an IBOutlet UIView for your splash screen.  Add the UIView on top of your window in MainWindow.xib and hook up its outlet to your new ivar. When your ApplicationDidFinishLaunching withOptions is called, start a NSTimer set to run once.  When the timer calls its selector or invocation, remove the view from the window.  So it will take a second to load Default.png and then your splash screen will be the first thing seen which will have your animation and then it will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for sharing of your view.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using UIImageView, for example

```
IBOutlet UIImageView* animationSplashImageView;
animationSplashImageView.animationImages = imageArray;
animationSplashImageView.animationDuration = 5;
animationSplashImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[animationSplashImageView startAnimating];
```

and you could test your splash using tool Splashx Free, which is on Apple App Store:
http://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/splashx-free/id500137095?mt=8